# Economics.SE: A call for papers

Tags: discussion, site-activity

In an attempt to put together something to represent the site I'd like to propose putting together a collection of working papers and articles written by regular contributors of the site.

I'd like to have between 4-5 written pieces to be consolidated into a pdf doc. Submissions will be accepted between April,15,2018-June,1,2018.

If you have something written you can send it to econjohnstackexchange@gmail.com.

Details of the work will follow if I receive the appropriate number of documents via email.

---

If you think this is a good idea or bad idea, let me know!

Comment: Sent you a paper

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Are you asking for original work, unpublished elsewhere? Do we need to own the copyright ourselves, or at least have permission to re-licence it? What are you intending to do with the consolidated doc?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers its a project I'd like to pursue with members of the site in a way to promote it. Original work primarily and the rights should be yours (though I think that is self explanatory). I intend on sharing the file afterwards to showcase the work.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I have no malicious intent here. Just want to promote the site.